# Vue-router routes to the wrong page, the link has to add a '#' before the path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

This is my home page:

[image]

and this is my blog page:

[image]

I'm using vue3, the code goes blow:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import Blogs from '../views/Blogs.vue';


const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home},
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: Home },
    { path: '/blogs', name: 'Blogs', component: Blogs },

];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router;
```

So, if the link is 'http://localhost:3000/blogs/', it should be my blog page, but it turns out to be home page.

[image]

The link has to be 'http://localhost:3000/#/blogs', so it can be routing to the blog page.

[image]

I don't get why I have to write a '/#/', before the actual path!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use '/#/' because you are using `createWebHashHistory()`, If there's no specific reason for using `createWebHashHistory()`, you should use `createWebHistory()` as it is the recommended way.

More info here:
https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use `createWebHistory` instead `createWebHashHistory`. More details [here](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).